# Embedding script with timeout in case server goes down

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to make sure an external script file won't block the viewed page,
if the server which serves it is "down" *(for example port 80 is blocked for some reason).*

Currently when I test by taking down the server (Apache) manually, or block that file via server's firewall,
I see the browser is trying to load the resource (script in that case), without success for long period of time, until it aborts.

Is there a way to get past this issue?

Comment: my script is already at the bottom, and already is async. I need a way to make sure it won't even try to load it more than X timeout.

Comment: Oh, now I understand: you want to shorten the timeout of script downloading?

Comment: wish I could delete this silly question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent post from Steve Souders analyzes this problem : **[Frontend - Single Point of Failure](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/06/01/frontend-spof/)**, by browsers and type of failure

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's time to start using jQuery?

Check out [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) info and search for `timeout` keyword.

**UPDATE:**

For this particular solution you could use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to fetch and execute remote scripts.

Comment: This isn't the same thing, the javascript file itself is timing out, jQuery won't do anything to solve this.

Comment: Why that? In the similar manner one could load a script and execute it locally.

Comment: well, this requires me to tell the website which installs my script, to also install jQuery.

Comment: ...or you could load it from your script :-)
http://www.codehouse.com/javascript/articles/external/